# Directly set every point in path's alpha channel on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, alpha, pixel-manipulation

Let's say I have a canvas with stuff on it, and I want to carve an ellipse in it's center, whose all of the pixels have an alpha of 0, to let everything behind the canvas to pass through, and given that previously the area now filled by the ellipse was something else, and said that, for performance reasons, I don't want to use putImageData, how would I do so?
And if there isn't a way, how would I carve an ellipse using putImageData?

Just to make it clear: I don't want to draw the html elements **on** the canvas, I want them to simply be in html **behind** it

Comment: Carve a canvas? Poor canvas.

Comment: @bjb568 you have to do what you have to do to keep going with your life... I know it's sad bro, but I really have to

Comment: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/

Comment: @rlemon yep, you've got it wrong: that's for later path rendering on canvas, not for showing stuff behind it, which is what I want

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/6nEpc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'` after you draw the frame to  *fill* the clipped shape(s).

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/6nEpc/